# How can you quote the original in an email reply to a Yammer message?

Tags: yammer

I prefer the traditional non-top-posting style of replying to email messages - quote the original with "bird tracks" (which you can get automatically with almost every email app), cut out irrelevant content that I am not responding to, then intersperse my replies among the reply lines of the original. This gives a nice conversational feel to the reply, and makes it very clear exactly what I am referring to in the original for each of my points.

But my company has now started using Yammer, and I am in a bind. I tried one of my signature non-top-posting replies to a Yammer message I received via email from a colleague. Yammer deleted almost the entire text of my reply, from the first line of quoted text onward, including all of my responses from that point on.

I tried changing the bird tracks to asterisks and reposting. Same effect.

Finally I posted the reply (the asterisks version) via the Yammer web interface, and that worked.

But I don't want to have to switch to the web interface, or a specialized desktop app, every time I need to respond to a Yammer message. Is there any way to stop Yammer from deleting all quoted text, and all other text that follows it, from email responses to Yammer messages?

Comment: This is a better question for http://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Brian Lyttle: While yammer does happen to have also a web interface, this question is not about that at all. But I agree that it's not your usual StackOverflow question either. I'm not sure where this question goes.

Comment: Honestly, you're attempting to use Yammer in a way that Yammer is not designed to be used. You're attempting to use non-standardized notation for your message and wanting to send that information through email (which is a series of layers in which your actual text is processed and reprocessed again several times before going to Yammer, where it has to be processed again and turned into web-safe text).

Comment: @michaelh: Actually, I am using 100% standard notation for email. But you are right, the answer is that Yammer isn't really designed to be used via email, at least not when using email in the normal way. Kind of like how you can control majordomo mailing lists via email, but only if you learn how to type the special email format for sending majordomo commands.